When try to add local database sqflite in my flutter project and try to run on crome(web) it gives me a error
today i try to add database SQFlite to my flutter project and  run it on web it gives error
the Ui is good according to the implementation but when i click on insert button what i define in my project for inserting data then i found  a error ->
DartError: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:3  throw_
packages/flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 320:7
first home.dart file
first home.dart file
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:local_database/db_handler.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("SQFLite Database"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: ()async{
      await DBHandler().insertData();
       // final data= await DBHandler().readData();
       // print(data);
          },child:  Text('Insert'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

second file where i create database and insert value in it
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class DBHandler{
  Database? _database;
// use get because it is getter method
  Future<Database?> get database  async{
    if(_database!=null){
      // means databse pahle se data he to yahi database ko return kar de
      // without creting and path findng

      return _database;
    }
    //path providing
    Directory directory =  await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    // join comes from path import
    // here a named mydatabase.db name file will crete
    String path=   join(directory.path,'mydatabase.db');
    // now open db file and crete table
    _database = await openDatabase(path,version: 1,onCreate: (db, version) {

      // execute means creating the table
      db.execute(
        '''
        CREATE TABLE databasetable(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,
        name TEXT ,
         age INTEGER
        '''
      );
     },);
    return _database;
  }
insertData()async{
    // the upper databse got store in db future wala
   Database? db= await database;
   db!.insert('databasetable',{
     'id':1,
     'name': 'John',
     'age': 18,
   });

}

readData() async{
  Database? db= await database;
  // for reading we use query
  // here data will comes in the form of list
  final list = await db!.query('databasetable');
  return list;
}


}

the error what i found when i try to run


The sqflite package only supports Android, iOS, and macOS platforms and is not compatible with Flutter web. You can find this information on its pub.dev page.
For cross-platform support, including Flutter web, you can use the idb_sqflite package instead. Check it out on its pub.dev page.
